# Mysql sort data from my table like described

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

My table looks like this, (let's just say it has no primary or any other key)

[image]

I want data to be in this format

[image]

help please :(

Comment: name_1 rows first?

Comment: my friend use at least a unique key so that you can sort all these records

Comment: Add your sample data in form of text not images

Comment: I wouldn't be posting this problem if I could use a key,, The table was given to me and I am not to make any changes to the schema,, thats why I posted

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the desired ordering.

Comment: Its like,, the value has name_1, name_2 and name_3 along with numeric amount values


the logic is to get the data in the order of `value` column but all the `name` column values must respect that,, 


like 

company_0_name | name_1,
company_0_amount | 30,
and all of the other `name` values which have `value` name_1

then all the `name` values which have `value` name_2 and so on

Comment: I'd say skip 2 rows per company, return 1 row instead. The the GROUP BY will be basic.

Comment: Im sorry can you please post the query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string functions you can nearly achieve that using following

```
select a.*
from demo a
join (select value,substring_index(name,'_',2) company_name 
      from demo 
      where substring_index(name,'_',-1) = 'name'
) b on substring_index(a.name,'_',2) = b.company_name
order by b.value asc,substring_index(a.name,'_',2) asc,substring_index(name,'_',-1) desc
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/JQUY43668)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT a.* FROM css_01 a LEFT JOIN (SELECT substring_index(name, '_', 2) as meta_like_key, value FROM css_01 wpm1 WHERE name like "company_%_name" ) b ON substring_index(a.name, '_', 2) = b.meta_like_key ORDER BY b.value ASC ,substring_index(a.name,'_',2) asc,a.name desc`

Comment: -\ ( ^ ^ )  /-

Faster than all of the other answers, thank you

Comment: No need to thanks...Its a pleasure to solve a problem like this :) Nice problem

Comment: @TheSuperKat This doesn't order the result set as per your expected output [see demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84927a/1)

Comment: Oh thank you for this demo,, I dint see that coming, I was wrong about this answer :)